# Which approaches traversing through a Typescript AST yield what?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

I started experimenting with the Typescript compiler, especially using the `ts-morph` wrapper. Currently I am attempting to traverse through the AST of a source file to deduce certain kinds of nodes and their properties and noticed at least three possibilities to traverse the respective AST which all yield different results:

- `SourceFile.getChildSyntaxListOrThrow().getChildren().forEach(...)` in combination with recursive `node.getChildren().forEach(...)` call which seemingly is the only approach to get trivia and comments as well.
- `SourceFile.getChildren().forEach(...)` sans `.getChildSyntaxListOrThrow()`
- `SourceFile.forEachDescendant(...)` without the necessity to to call a `visitNode` handler for child node
- `SourceFile.forEachChild(...)` that does not yield keywords

Unfortunately I cannot seem to understand the exact difference to fully figure which approach is best in which case. So the question is "which approaches traversing through a Typescript AST yield what?"